# Multiple Iterators and Clipping in ArcGIS ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, clip, iterator

I have two separate polygon layers. One layer consists of voronoi polygons. The second layer consists of buffers, many of which overlap.

I need to do is iterate through each voronoi, clip only the buffer which has its center within the polygon, and then recombine all the clipped polygons in to one layer.

Since I only want each clip to be of one unique voronoi and one unique buffer polygon, my inclination was to use multiple iterators, but that does not appear to be possible in ModelBuilder.

Is there any way to do this in ModelBuilder?

Comment: I think I can picture what you are describing but could you include a diagram of your Voronoi polygons and buffers overlaid, please?  Do you still have the point feature class or whatever was used to generate your buffers?  The reason I ask is that it may be easier to work with that since you want to use their centres.  I suspect ArcPy will be easier to do this but it may not be beyond ModelBuilder.

Comment: You could create a seperate model for each iteration, then add as many as you like to one model as tools. Give it a go, it should work ...let us know.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Voronoi Polygons with overlaid buffers]

I do have the original feature class. But unfortunately I don't think it would have worked to start with that. As you can see, the buffers overlap the polygon boundaries. Clipping would bring in areas from other polygons. Intersecting would have created multiple sub-polygons.

However, it turns out that this task was trivial to complete in Spatialite. Because the polygons and buffers shared a unique id (they were both derived from the same point data), I was able to use the Intersection function in spatialite to complete the task. 4 lines of code.